# Cloning Label leads to freezing C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

In my program I need to copy a Label in Windows Forms, and I implemented it the following way:

```
public partial class Resizer : Form
{
    public Resizer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private Control toChange = new Control();
    private Control selected = new Control();

    private bool readyToMove = false;
    private Point offset;

    private void pictureBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selected.Location = ((Control)sender).Location;
        selected.Size = ((Control)sender).Size;
    }

    private void backClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selected = null;
    }

    private void Resizer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox4.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.dynamicMouseDown);
        pictureBox4.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.dynamicMouseMove);
        pictureBox4.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(this.dynamicMouseUp);

    }

    private void dynamicMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        toChange = (Control)sender;
        selected.Location = ((Control)sender).Location;
        selected.Size = ((Control)sender).Size;
        readyToMove = true;
        offset = new Point(PointToClient(MousePosition).X - selected.Location.X, 
                           PointToClient(MousePosition).Y - selected.Location.Y);
    }

    private void dynamicMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (readyToMove)
        {
            selected.Location = new Point(PointToClient(MousePosition).X-offset.X,
                                          PointToClient(MousePosition).Y- offset.Y);
            this.Update();
        }
    }

    private void dynamicMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        toChange.Location = selected.Location;
        readyToMove = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pBox = (PictureBox)CloneObject(this.pictureBox4);
        this.Controls.Add(pBox);
//pBox.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.dynamicMouseDown);
//pBox.MouseMove += new MouseEventhandler(this.dynamicMouseMove);
//pBox.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(this.dynamicMouseUp);
//these eventhandlers did not help...

    }

    private object cloneObject(object o)
    {
        Type t = o.GetType();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();

        Object p = t.InvokeMember("", 
                                  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, 
                                  null, 
                                  o, 
                                  null);

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            if (pi.CanWrite)
                 pi.SetValue(p, pi.GetValue(o, null), null);
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

old problem:
The problem is that as soon as I click on the `labelOrigin`, the Window freezes and I can't close the form anymore.  Why is that and how can I fix it?
Now:
As you can see, this implements a drag&drop where by pressing a button, you can duplicate a form..
the problem is, that the new pBox is not movable and does lead to graphical errors.. 
this code should work on a simple form after adding a button1 and a pictureBox4

Comment: Why complicate it so heavily? If you need to clone just a Label then all you need to copy is the x,y,text and if you set some custom stuff(width, height, font).

Comment: because later I want to do it with other Controls.. and yes, there sill be different settings that have been changed from standard.. by this I want to avoid to rewrite an new function for all cases..

Comment: Did you try putting the code into a try catch block? Otherwise if there are no errors even with that then the foreach must be in a infinite loop somehow

Comment: Yes, add a `try-catch` around that code...it's likely not "freezing", it's probably throwing a quiet exception and never returning.

Comment: no, I did the debugging and it seems to execute all the code without any problem...

Comment: Can you post reproducable example? I tried your code, and it's not freezing for me at all.

Comment: bizare... the only thing I changed in my (full) code was that instead of copying all the properties manually I used the CopyObject funtion and then it crashed.. but when I did this function in a new windows form, it worked partially..(see edit)

Comment: "because later I want to do it with other Controls" -- IMHO this approach is doomed to failure. There's too much object-specific housekeeping for you to be able to simply use default initialization and then copy public properties from one instance to another. I mean, I don't see any specific reason the above code should fail to work, but it also doesn't surprise me at all that it doesn't.